# Unable to compile SASS, relative path ~ not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, sass

I am having a problem compiling the SASS files for a React project I am working on. This worked fine yesterday morning, but starting in the afternoon, when I run the compiler, I get the following error:

```
Compilation Error
Error: File "{path removed to protect the innocent}\components\~bootstrap-sass\assets\stylesheets\bootstrap\variables" not found
    on line 2 of sass/{path removed to protect the innocent}\components\_bootstrap_custom.scss
    from line 2 of sass/{path removed to protect the innocent}\components\{project name}.scss
>> @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";
```

I tried going back to previous branches that I know were working, but nothing seems to fix it.

I have tried this on three different machines, two running Windows 10 and one running Zorin Linux version 12.  No one else on the team I am working with is having the same problem.

My best guess is that webpack is not recognizing the relative path to pull the bootstrap files from node_modules.  Oddly enough, the prod build process works just fine.

The webpack.config.dev.js file has what seems to be the correct setup for loading .sass files.

```
loader: "sass-loader",
options: {
  includePaths: [
    paths.appSrc,
    ""
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure what else I can be missing.

Comment: Post an example of your relative path in code

Comment: This is from the bootstrap_custom.scss mentioned above:

`@import "variables";`
`@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";`
`@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins";`

Comment: Did you notice in the error that it is looking for the files in the `components` folder but you mentioned they are located in the `node_modules` folder?

Comment: The tilde should tell webpack to look in the node_modules folder, right?  None of these files have changed in at least ten months.

Comment: You said reverting to an old commit didn't fix your problem even though it used to work on that commit?

Comment: Yes, it must be something environment related, though what that could be I don't know.

Comment: Try deleting bootstrap and re-installing it. Or try an older version of bootstrap.